# How to match two or more spaces in java.util.Scanner?

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I have row of numbers which should be splitted by space.

But space might be long or short or just single space.

I fail to write regex that would split numbers correctly . Here is my attempt:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String next = scanner.next();

    System.out.println("split=" + Arrays.toString(next.split("\\s{1,}")));
}
```

Help me to split by any number of spaces between figures.

**EDIT:** Here is one of rows which should be splitted to get array of integers:

```
108 125 145  48  49  77  65  62  93 121 114 148 134 129 170
```

My attempts were

```
inputScanner.nextLine().split("\\s{1,}");
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem ? Can you show some sample input and output ?

Comment: What output you expect from edit?

Comment: I want to get array of integers - Integer[] numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `split("\\s+");` for one or more spaces.

And why do you need to split if you're just getting the next token from the scanner?

```
String next = scanner.next();
```

Maybe you want

```
String next = scanner.nextLine();

System.out.println("split=" + Arrays.toString(next.split("\\s+")));
```

If you want to get the Integer values of an entire line you can do this

```
String[] numString = next.split("\\s+");
int[] nums = new int[numString.length];

for (int i = 0; i < numString.length; i++){
    nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(numString[i].trim());
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
```

Comment: Despite the fact that `\\s+` means `\\s{1,}` which OP is already using +1 for explaining problem with `next()` and suggesting `nextLine()`.

Comment: @peeskillet. My solution is `nextLine.replaceAll("(\\s+)", ",");`. But this sometimes causes the first character to be `,`, So I also replaced it with "" . And now 247881 lines of integers are read ok

Comment: So your question is how can you remove that first `,`?

Comment: You should just post a new question, labeled "How to avoid replaceAll((\\s+), ",") from adding comma to begging of String". Or "Why does replaceAll read the first character of my String as empty space?"

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi it seems that your string have space at start. If so try to remove it using `trim()` method like `nextLine.trim().replaceAll("(\\s+)", ",");`

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you can solve your problem easily using `List<Integer>`

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    myList.add(scanner.nextInt());
}
```

and later if you really need `Integer[]` array you can create one with

```
Integer[] array = myList.toArray(new Integer[myList.size()]);
```

Comment: This is good but I need to read line by line with method readLine and then deal with String.+1 anyway

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi can I ask why you have to read your data with `readLine()` (or maybe `nextLine()` if we are talking about Scanner)?

Comment: I have mad school task. Please see my next comment

Answer (score 0):

To match at least `2` or more spaces use regex `\s{2,}`

```
System.out.println("split=" + Arrays.toString(next.split("\\s{2,}")));
```

Comment: `But space might be long or short or just single space.`

Comment: @anubhava, OP wants at least 2 or more.

Comment: You're probably a good mind reader but OP wrote: `or just single space`

Comment: What you are saying in your answer is true, but this doesn't solve OP problem. Please correct or delete your answer since right now it doesn't help anyone.